# How can I tell if an exe opened with subprocess has finished launching?

Tags: python, subprocess, exe

I have a script that opens a .exe using subprocess. I'm wondering if there's a way I can tell when that .exe has finished launching?

I'm looking for something like:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['myFile.exe'])

While myFile.exe is still opening:

    # still loading, do nothing

print("exe finished opening")
```

I've seen ways to check if the .exe has been closed by the user, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define "finished launching"?

Comment: I have a GUI script that I packaged as an 'onefile' exe using pyinstaller. It's got a few asset files and libraries it uses, so after clicking the exe, it takes about 10 seconds for the GUI to show up on the screen. So I consider "finished launching" to be when when the exe is done being unpacked and the script starts

Comment: I doubt that there is a generic way to achieve this, as your application appears as just 'running' to the subprocess handler. There isn't really a 'state' which depicts 'loaded' in your sense. You could send some data to stdout or stderr whenever your GUI has appeared I guess and react or wait for that in the script.

Comment: @FloWil that could be a possibility. So you're saying the main script of my exe, which is run when the exe finishes "loading", could send a message back to my first run script? Could you explain that a little further? I think that would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as a result from the discussion in the comments.

In order to detect the state of your exe beeing finished with *loading* you need the subprocess to signal that state to the calling script as there is no generic definition or way to detect that state (eg. through exit codes etc.).

A bit crude but also the most simple solution could be to let your exe print a defined string to stdout and make the subprocess handler above listen to it.

When you have your exe print a string like `EXE Loaded.` on stdout once it reaches your desired state (GUI visible or whatever),
you then would poll (or better use some sort of async io stuff :) ) the subprocess output from the calling script like so:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['myFile.exe'], stdout=PIPE)

while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if process.poll() is not None and output == 'EXE Loaded.':
        break
```

This will basically poll the stdout of the launched exe and continue to do so until it receives `EXE Loaded.` as string.
Please be aware that this shall just explain the most basic idea behind it.
In a real example you would probably use some sort of more modern asynchronous wait stuff . Also think about using the `run` function like mentioned in the other answer. It's advised to not use POpen directly unless you cannot make due with the higher level API of `subprocess`.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to put this together. I'm trying to replicate it but it looks like `process.stdout` is coming in as `NoneType`, so it fails to call `readline()` on it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was able to get around that by adding `stdout=PIPE` to the subprocess call. Although, it still looks like output only gets called when the exe is terminated...

Comment: That maybe because the process wasn't polled before. I changed the break condition to always execute the poll. 
You might also want to try to use POpen.communicate() instead.

Comment: it looks like that did it, thank you so much for the help! I've marked it as the correct answer. You may want to add `stdout=PIPE` to your subprocess line though, as I needed that included for this to work.

Comment: HTH. Added the stdout argument accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use `subprocess.Popen`, it is recommended to use `subprocess.run` instead. If you use `run` instead, the python script waits until `run` returns before continuing.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

If you for some reason have to use `Popen` you could call `Popen.wait` for example, but I would just use `run`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It looks like run will only return when I close the exe. What I'm looking for is something that will tell me when the .exe finishes unpacking, and starts running the main script